# Zabbix "No Such Object available on this agent at this OID" while MIB already added

Tags: snmp, zabbix

I am stuck with Zabbix Import MIB. In fact, the MIB already imported to MIB database. But, it still alerts: "No Such Object available on this agent at this OID"

Here I show you what I did:

I am using Zabbix 3.4

Firstly, I wanted to monitor the CPU of HPE Router. However, Zabbix shows that could not do that. So I went to add MIB manually.

```
ops2:/tmp$ snmptranslate -IR -On hpSwitchCpuStat
Unknown object identifier: hpSwitchCpuStat
```

then download MIB and import to MIB local server

```
ops2:/usr/share/snmp/mibs# snmptranslate -m +STATISTICS-MIB -IR -On hpSwitchCpuStat
```

after that, I run

```
@ops2:/usr/share/snmp/mibs# snmptranslate -m +STATISTICS-MIB -IR -On hpSwitchCpuStat
.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.5.1.9.6.1
```

and

```
ops2:/usr/share/snmp/mibs# snmptranslate -On STATISTICS-MIB::hpSwitchCpuStat
.1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.5.1.9.6.1

ops2:/usr/share/snmp/mib2c-data# snmpwalk -v2c -c public 10.10.10.1
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: HPE Series Router MSR930
HPE Comware Platform Software
Comware Software Version 5.20, Release 2514P14
Copyright(c) 2010-2015 Hewlett-Packard Enterprise Development LP
```

also added

```
ops2:/usr/share/snmp/mib2c-data# vim /etc/snmp/snmp.conf
mibs +STATISTICS-MIB
```

As I see, the Object already existed. SNMP Translate found it. But, Zabbix Web Frontend still could not find it. It still alerts: 
No Such Object available on this agent at this OID

[image]
Could you please give me any advices? Thank you.

Comment: `snmptranslate`  only looks for the OID in the MIB file; `snmpget`  and Zabbix will look for the OID in the actual device. What happens if you do a `snmpwalk -v2c -c public 10.10.10.1 STATISTICS-MIB::hpSwitchCpuStat` ?

Comment: following your suggest, here are the result of snmpwalk:
`ops2:~$ snmpwalk -v2c -c public 10.10.10.1 STATISTICS-MIB::hpSwitchCpuStat
STATISTICS-MIB::hpSwitchCpuStat = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID`. Is that mean this OID doesn't exist in HPE Router? If that's right, can I add OID to HPE device directly? Thank for your help.

Comment: Yes, that'a exactly what it means. And no, not without a firmware update to the router. (Adding just the OID number is not enough; you would also have to add some program code to actually collect the data and format it for transmitting in a SNMP packet.)

Comment: @telcoM do you have any example for me? then I can refer it.

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible without the programming documentation for the router hardware (which will probably be accessible to HPE employees of the appropriate department only). And if the firmware is protected with a cryptographic signature, you could not get your custom firmware updated into the router anyway unless you somehow had HPE's private signing keys.

Comment: If you want to know more about the task involved, you might want to see [this net-snmp FAQ entry](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/FAQ.html#I_ve_installed_a_new_MIB_file___Why_can_t_I_query_it_) and then next entry after that one. On a router firmware there is probably no possibility to run external commands or shell scripts or other extensions, so you would have to get the source code of the router's internal SNMP agent and extend it; reading the CODING section of the `net-snmp` FAQ might be informative.

Comment: that's enterprise model, so hard to expose it to intend the code into firmware. HPE should be provided it as a latest firmware as I thought. Thank @telcoM for your help.

Answer (score 1):

"No Such Object available" usually indicates that the entry you are querying is not present.
In your description, I did not see information on what exact OID you used in the Zabbix item. Notably, was it numeric or short form, and what exactly did it point at?

In your `snmpwalk` output you do not show walking the OID in question, so it is not very relevant for this specific problem.

A common mistake is to use a node somewhere up the tree, not a leaf node. To find out whether that is what you are doing, try `snmpget` with the exact same OID you have in the Zabbix item. If it fails, first find an OID that works with `snmpget`. If you do `snmpwalk` on the OID you have currently, it would normally show you what is underneath, and would allow picking the correct OID for the item.

Comment: thank @ricklv, it seems the OID doesn't exist in HPE router. I did some command as `ops2:~$ snmpget -v2c -c public 10.10.10.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.5.1.9.6.1
STATISTICS-MIB::hpSwitchCpuStat = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID` and `ops2:~$ snmpwalk -v2c -c public 10.10.10.1 STATISTICS-MIB::hpSwitchCpuStat
STATISTICS-MIB::hpSwitchCpuStat = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID`

The OID what I need to monitor is 1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.5.1.9.6.1 of hpSwitchCpuStat. It shows the CPU state.